# "Cancha Techada" in English

Tags: meaning, translation

I entered "cancha techada" into a translator, and it gave me "indoor court."

In my school we have a court (like a tennis or basketball court), but it isn't indoors. The court just has a roof on it, and we call it a "cancha techada."

What is the correct English word or phrase for this?

Comment: Can you post a picture of something like it?  It sounds like it's outdoors, and yet it has a roof on it, so I'm having trouble picturing it.  Maybe "covered courtyard"?  Try looking up "covered courtyard" and see if the pictures look like what you're thinking of.

Comment: @stangdon Imagine the sides are open but it's a field roofed.

Comment: https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=cancha+techada&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-us&client=safari&gfe_rd=cr&ei=AlqnV52wNcna8geR46eYAg#gfe_rd=cr&imgrc=jz8WgI6kgNmWwM%3A

Comment: @EliasOrozco I think it's a bit strange that the translator didn't give you "roofed court".

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking for "covered court", although a covered court could be indoors or outdoors. You could also call it a "shaded court," meaning it has something to block the sun:

> [**shade**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/shade#shade__23)
>   Screen from direct light:
>   "*She shaded her eyes against the sun*"
>
> Cover, moderate, or exclude the light of:
>   "*He shaded the torch with his hand*"

Using "shaded" would imply that the court is outdoors, as if it was indoors it's less likely that there would be a reason to block the sun.

You could also call it a "sheltered" court:

> [**sheltered**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sheltered)
>   (Of a place) protected from bad weather:
>   "*the plants need a shady, sheltered spot in the garden*"

Again, this implies that it is outdoors because there would be no reason to protect an indoor court from bad weather.

I am assuming that "cancha techada" refers to a court on which sport is played, as the results I got when searching for images of them were all sports courts.

Answer (score 2):

Searching around, I found that the structure was often called a *shade structure* [[1]](https://shade-n-net.com/shade-structures/recreational/outdoor-basketball-court-shade/), or a *canopy structure* [[2]](http://www.shadecomforts.com/albums/sport-court-sun-shade-canopies/).

This leads me to believe that you could easily call them ***shaded*** or ***canopied*** courts.

I also found that they were called ***covered courts***. Here is [one example](http://donahuefavret.com/commercial-construction-project/mary-queen-of-peace-covered-court-play-area/).